# Передача данных Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Почему этот код не работает?

Все же вроде верно написано!

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <title>
    Test application!
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="index.html" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" />

        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var index = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');
var http = require('http');
var app = require('express')(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf8'});
    res.end(index);
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');

app.use("/index.html", bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.post("/index.html", function(req, res, next) {

    console.dir(req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Your name is' + req.body.first_name);
});
```

Comment: А что ожидается от кода?

Comment: Чтобы данные введенные в текстовое поле отправлялись на сервер,а потом возвращались на эту же страницу с сервера

Comment: А как Вы определяете, что данные не возвращаются назад?

Comment: Я считал что они должны отобразиться на странице? или нет?

Comment: Ok. А как сделать чтобы они отображались на странице?

Comment: Я ошибся, Вы правильно думаете. Данные должны отобразиться на странице. Только что проверил. Но я с `express` не работаю. Тестировал с помощью нативных инструментов

Comment: Покажите как вы делаете?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, потому что биндите сервер через `http`, а не через `express`.

С экспрессом обычно делается так:

```
var app = require('express')();
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'), 
    path = require('path'); 

// вместо http.createServer..., напишите просто
app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});

app.use('/index.html', bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res, next) {    // при гете - отдаем файл
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
app.post('/index.html', function(req, res, next) {   // при посте - строку с именем из реквеста
  res.send('Your name is ' + req.body.first_name);
});
```

[RunKit endpoint](https://runkit.io/yar85/questions-821297/branches/master/)

Answer (score 1):

В качестве ответа на комментарий. Только я не парсил запрос, а просто вывел его в консоли. Ответ вернул произвольный.

```
const fs = require("fs"),
      http = require ("http"),
      url = require("url"),
      index = fs.readFileSync('./index.html'),
      port = 3000,
      server = http.createServer();

server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Сервер запущен по адресу localhost:"+port);
    console.log("*****************************************************************");
})

server.on("request", function(req, res){
    if (req.method == "GET") {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end(index)
    } else if (req.method == "POST") {
        var data ="";
        req.on('data', function(chunk){
            data += chunk;
        })
        req.on("end", function(){
            console.log(data)
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            res.end("Very good");
        });
    }
});
```